# Reading a single line from a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out how to nicely read lines from a file (similar to a BufferedReader in Java). I have a file which contains 3 lines, the third line contains a massive JSON string which I want to decode into JavaScript objects. I'd prefer not to use PHP and do it all within my JavaScript if that's possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the development context? Are you using nodejs? Are you trying to do this on the browser?

Comment: the first question I would ask is where is the file ?

Comment: the file is located on my system. I just want to read the third line from it and extract the JSON string

Comment: I'm developing everything locally for now

Answer (score 1):

You have to use File API of HTML5, if you want to be able to read the file off local system.
call the [readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsText%28%29) function on your filereader

```
reader.readAsText(fileObject,"UTF-8");
```

and then read each line from there, i dont think there is a read by line.

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("read success");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
```

Also note you have to use the window.requestFileSystem or window.webkitRequestFileSystem stuff to be allowed, and maybe as well as changing a browser setting to allow reading local files.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, opt_errorCallback)
```

[Full FileSystem tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Answer (score 0):

js does not have access to the file system.

Comment: That's not very true.  See the HTML5 file APIs.

Comment: @SLaks > I was just reading back info on this, and actually the file still needs to be put somehow in the page, was it with an input file or a drag and drop. So I don't think Javascript as indeed access to the file system, but this API makes the file available through the browser...

Comment: JS have file access if it implements the correct File API, and setting a correct request to use the filesystem.